# Disabling the login form and redirect users on logout without headers sent php warning

Tags: login

I have created my own login and registration forms so i needed a way to disable the standard login form.

Also i needed the user to be redirected on logout to somewhere else and not the login form.

I came up with this logic. Opened `wp-login.php` and found the first hook. That was `login_head`.

So i hooked into this and i just redirect unless the user gives a secret token.

```
function e4_login_form_disable() {
        if ( ! isset( $_GET['gandalf'] ) || $_GET['gandalf'] != 'thewhite' ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Am i ok with this or i am missing something?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** I am getting the following warning: `"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/site/wp-login.php:63) in site/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1171 "`

It seems like it can be made to work if you enable `output_buffering` in php.ini and place this file in directory where the .php file that creates the warning resides.

But it seems like a "hack"...

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Is it working? What's broken?

Comment: I added the warning i am getting on my live site. On my localhost the redirect is working...

Comment: lol yes that warning is pretty important to include! Adding answer for you now

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer again now that you've also included that the headers sent error is coming from wp-login.php. _Please_ in future provide all useful information - __especially__ errors - when you ask your original question. Would've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you are receiving is because you can't redirect the browser to another page once you have already sent content for the current page to it.

The rest of the error tells you the exact file that is sending the content you don't yet want. You need to either:

- ensure you run your redirect in an earlier hook, *before* this content has the chance to be output; or
- fix whatever is causing this content to be output so that the redirect will function as intended

In your case, the output is coming from `wp-login.php` as it outputs the actual login form. This means you're going to have to hook in *before* this happens.

I can see what you've done here, and it's a common error: you've found the `login_head` action referred to earlier in this function (around line 37 of `wp-login.php`), and attempted to hook into it. The thing is, the code `add_action( 'login_head', 'wp_no_robots' );` that you've seen here is actually *hooking into* `login_head` itself; it's not running the action.

Looking further into `wp-login.php`, within this same function, we find `do_action( 'login_head' );` at around line 98 (notice `do_action` rather than `add_action`). **This** is when your hooked code is actually running, which unfortunately is after the output that has already been sent by Wordpress (the start of the login page).

So, we need to find ourselves an earlier hook. Because we're redirecting, we really should go as early as possible, otherwise we might be making Wordpress do a lot of work it's just going to have to do all over again on the page we redirect to. Having a look at the [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) on the Codex, `init` is a pretty early hook that sounds like it might meet our needs.

Excellent. Try modifying your hooked function to use `init` instead of `login_head`.

**BUT**, there's one more step we need to take... otherwise we're going to redirect *every* user on *every* page!

Inside your function, you need to now also check that it is the login page that is being viewed. Unfortunately Wordpress doesn't offer an `is_login_page()` function, so we can do this instead with a quick statement that checks the global `pagenow` variable:

```
if($GLOBALS["pagenow"] == "wp-login.php"){ /* do redirect here */ }
```

Putting all this together, you should now successfully be able to redirect away from the login page (I haven't tested all this yet though!):

```
function e4_login_form_disable() {
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] == 'wp-login.php' ){
        if ( ! isset( $_GET['gandalf'] ) || $_GET['gandalf'] != 'thewhite' ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'e4_login_form_disable');
```

In regards to output buffering, yes this does technically work, but it's definitely hacky, and you shouldn't use it when there's an alternative available. It'll slow down each redirect slightly too.

Comment: Thanks!. Ii added the specific file info that he complains about. Unfortunately i cant seem to find an earlier hook than that..

Comment: Also as i added , this works ok on localhost. On the live site i am getting the warning.

Comment: How did you go with this @e4rthdog?

Comment: This totally addressed my issue. Similarly to OP I'm checking a $_GET _wpnonce on the login page and redirecting to home_url() if it fails validation. No errors on my local or even staging sites but was getting "Cannot modify header information" on production. Switching from `login_head` to `init` and wrapping in `pagenow` nailed it. Thanks, @Tim Malone